# Java Rest how to make an overall get filter

Tags: java, rest

I am writing a REST service using jersey 2 and servlet 3. I have custom GET methods, all of which first look if the request has certain headers. If headers are not present, I am throwing an exception. Is there a way to provide a "parent-like" @GET method, which would reject requests withouth certain headers before they proceed to a corresponding @Path-link? Like, if my service has a name myService, and the @Path is "getHello", how to check for the headers first before going to myService/getHello annotated method?

Comment: If you are using Spring you can use Interceptors to validate your headers.

Comment: Did you check this https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html - ContainerRequestFilter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `ContainerRequestFilter` and check the method

```
@Provider
public class CheckHeaderFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext context) {
        if (context.getMethod().toUpperCase().equals("GET")) {
            String header = context.getHeaderString("SomeHeader");
            MultivaluedMap<String, String> headers = context.getHeaders();
            if(notValidHEaders) {
                context.abortWith(Response.status(400).entity("Bad").build());
                // or throw WebApplicationException
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you are using package scanning to register resources, the filter should also get picked up and registered because of the `@Provider` annotation. Otherwise, you will need to register it yourself

**See also:**

- [Filters and Interceptors](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html)